# How to call/use libfuzzer for custom API?

Tags: c++, llvm, clang++, fuzzing

I'am new to `libfuzzer`: https://llvm.org/docs/LibFuzzer.html. I took time to read the doc and googling... But I feel like I still miss basic concepts when dealing with real world examples?! Maybe I missed relevant doc/examples: if so, feel free to let me know.

The doc example here (like other very basic examples you may find googling) https://github.com/google/fuzzing/blob/master/tutorial/libFuzzer/fuzz_me.cc is OK: `libfuzzer` runs and crash as expected.

Now, say I have a real life code with real life API like such:

```
void MyAPI(std::vector<double> const& msg, size_t const& idx)
```

How can I take inputs provided by `libfuzzer` and turn them into arguments for `MyAPI`:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void MyAPI(std::vector<std::string> const& msg, size_t const& idx) {
  std::cout << msg[idx] << std::endl; // BUG here: idx must be < msg.size().
}

bool FuzzAPI(const uint8_t *Data, size_t Size) {
  // How to call MyAPI from here ?
}

extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *Data, size_t Size) {
  FuzzAPI(Data, Size);
  return 0;
}
```

I don't know what is the value of `Size` is, nor, the content of `Data` as, if I get this correctly, they are randomly generated by the fuzzer: so how can I turn them into something `MyAPI` needs?

Next, what if `MyAPI` needs a filename as an argument like such?

```
>> cat helloworld.txt 
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
```

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

void MyAPI(std::string const& filename, size_t const& idx) {
  ifstream myfile(filename.c_str()); // filename typically is helloworld.txt
  std::string line;
  std::vector<std::string> msg;
  while (std::getline(myfile, line)) {
    msg.push_back(line);
  }
  std::cout << msg[idx] << std::endl; // BUG here: idx must be < msg.size().
}

bool FuzzAPI(const uint8_t *Data, size_t Size) {
  // How to call MyAPI from here ?
}

extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *Data, size_t Size) {
  FuzzAPI(Data, Size);
  return 0;
}
```

I understand the notion of corpus to be input data I would have passed to `MyAPI` (the way you would in CI for instance), but, it's not clear to me how to define this corpus (what's supposed to be inside it) nor how the fuzzer will handle it (and in the end what I get in `Data` - do I get random number ? Or lines of the file ? Or something different ?). For instance, how to set an initial corpus to be 'msg.assign(10, 'hello world!')' or a file 'hello_world.txt' containing 10 'hello world!' lines.

Looks to me like basic usage / concepts... But surprisingly I had a hard time to find examples. How one is supposed to fuzz such kind of API? What should be the (conversion) logic between `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput` and `MyAPI`? Can somebody provide working examples?

Comment: `Size` is the length of the buffer `Data`. I'd suggest reading [this](https://github.com/google/fuzzing/blob/master/docs/split-inputs.md), and maybe using FDP there to help you. e.g. You'd read some of the input into idx, next as len for first element, etc. If the input is expected in a file, your wrapper can create that.

Comment: OK. `libfuzzer` handles corpus as raw binary files (not as txt files - human meaning) right? So raw binary data read from corpus files are passed into `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput` as `Data` pointer of length `Size`, correct?

Comment: The (binary) corpus files are used as initial inputs, and will be passed as you say. You can request ASCII only inputs, if you really want them (`-only_ascii`), though.

Comment: OK. This answers my questions: best is to generate "hand-made" binary corpus (containing samples of `MyAPI` inputs), they will be passed to `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput` via `Data`, so then it's possible to read them back there and call then `MyAPI`. This mechanism was not clear to me after reading the doc.